# Correct gulp-destination

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I have gulp configured the first time on my project with the global and local version 3.9.1 and set up a gulp-watch-task like that:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

// vars
var SCSS_PATH ='styles/**/*.scss';
var DIST_CSS_PATH ='css/';

// Styles for SCSS
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return gulp.src(SCSS_PATH)
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(DIST_CSS_PATH));
});

// Watch-Task
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(SCSS_PATH, ['styles'])
});
```

Now my watch task runs successfully and creates a css-file minified and prefixed. BUT it does created in **css/local.css/sw.css** which is obviously not correct. What I want it to be created is **css/sw.css** What do I do wrong there and why is that?

Comment: Is there a styles/local.css/  folder initially?  So styles/local.css/sw.scss?

Comment: nope. That's the strange thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use globs (**) it will keep the original folder structure. You can also choose the base for `gulp.src` and `gulp.dest`, as explained [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsbase).

What you want, however, is to flatten the folder structure. You can do that with [gulp-flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten).

It would be end up as something like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var flatten = require('gulp-flatten');

// vars
var SCSS_PATH ='styles/**/*.scss';
var DIST_CSS_PATH ='css/';

// Styles for SCSS
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return gulp.src(SCSS_PATH)
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(flatten())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(DIST_CSS_PATH));
});

// Watch-Task
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(SCSS_PATH, ['styles'])
});
```

I didn't really check with your code, but it worked in one of my build systems.